# Ionic FileUploadOptions is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

> ionic.bundle.js:26771 ReferenceError: FileUploadOptions is not defined

I Keep receiving this error even though, The Cordova files are installed:

**cordova-plugin-file**

**cordova-plugin-file-transfer**

and also after adding `DeviceReady()` :

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() { 
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['starter']);
  }, false);
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova','starter.controllers'])
```

**My Code**

```
..
 $scope.upload = function() {


console.log('2');
        $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading...'});
console.log('3');
        var fileURL = $scope.test;
console.log('4', fileURL);
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
console.log('5');
..
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: **one question:** testing in real device or in browser?

Comment: Browser, reason is to test in local service. @Naitik

Comment: you need to test in real device with assign local ip address in local service

Comment: Yes, I get it, but it is much more productive and easy when able to use break points. Otherwise I will have to run through IIS and to be honest I'm a noob.  Isn't there a way for me to use this class in a browser? @Naitik

Comment: testing in android device?

Comment: then you can run your app from xcode in device and in safari you can enable developer mode and debug app of device in safari...

Comment: one more thing keep your phone connected.. :D

Comment: Do mean by logging the results through Safari? @Naitik

Comment: go through http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html this is your cup of tea.. ;)

Comment: Wish I saw this before starting IOS dev, would have saved me hours of testing.. :]

Comment: Your debugging method helps a lot if you want to you can add it as an answer? @Naitik

Comment: sure, i am going to add answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to test in **real device** with assign local ip address in local service.

according to your comment you try in browser because you want to debug your app and you are using IOS platform.

so for test real device for ios you just need to follow:

[Debug real ios device](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html)

for test real device android you need to run your app in andorid keep connect that device with your machine and in chrome you just go to **chrome://inspect/#devices** there you can find your app in device you just need to do inspect there and you can debug you android app as well.

I know it already helps you a lot but i add answer here so other can also get solution. :)

Happy Coding.

Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

In ionic you are using ngCordova, not cordova directly, so you don't need to define your options like that, you only have to pass a regular object, ngCordova takes care of the rest for you.

`var options = {};`

You have to work with the API of the $cordovaFileTransfer service, which wraps the cordova plugin, check out these  <s>[docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/)</s> .

Edit:

> Above link is spam.Please don't click.